# "Undefined reference to _imp__" with MinGW on Eclipse

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a third-party C++ code on Eclipse but I get some errors at the linking level. In particular, it seems that I can't link against the import libraries that I'm in possession (the ones with .lib extension), as you can see from the messages in the build log:

[build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvc9D.png)

I believe I set the path to the libraries correctly and maybe you can confirm this:

[libraries' paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EfWn.png)

The linker is able to find those libraries (in this case xsensdeviceapi64.lib and xstypes64.lib), so I don´t understand the origin of these errors. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the libraries built with MinGW?

Comment: That, I don´t know, I only know that they were built using Visual Studio and provided by the company together with the sensor that I'm using.

Comment: EDIT: my bad, I've just realised that I was using MinGW32 while the libraries are 64. Taking this into account, I manage to make it work. Thank the same for trying to help me!